# How to add padding to bottom of div on hover in Avada theme?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, wordpress-theming, css-animations

How can I add padding (or use CSS transformY or JavaScript) to add padding to bottom of divs in a grid (it doesn't have to be padding I just want the background colour to slide down 15px on hover without pushing the other content/boxes downwards).

Each div needs to be stretched so that they are the same height -> [Video of desired hover effect](https://www.loom.com/share/b039eb885717402aa41ef6682324e834)

Video of column stretch and hover animations here:
[Testing of boxes with following CSS code + Avada page builder](https://www.loom.com/share/50ff39d36e8e4ae3bb9d1d6b56e44422)

- Only the higher purple box animates the bottom padding
- The bottom 2 boxes here animate nicley because they are same height

```
.blackcontainer:hover .bb_text_description {
     padding-bottom:15px;
     transition: all 0.2s;
     color:#fff!important;
}
 .blackcontainer .bb_text_description {
     transition: all 0.2s;
     color:#fff!important;
}
 .blackcontainer .fusion-image-element {
     overflow-x: clip;
}
 .blackcontainer .bb_img img {
     transform: scale(1);
     transition: transform 0.2s linear;
     transform-origin: bottom center;
     z-index:1!important;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .bb_img img {
     transform: scale(1.03);
     transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
 .blackcontainer .bb_img {
     transform: scale(1);
     transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .bb_img {
     transform: scale(1.1);
     transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
/*green*/
 .hover-underline-animation-green h3 {
     box-shadow: inset 0 -0.0em #78d64b;
     display: inline;
     transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .hover-underline-animation-green h3 {
     box-shadow: inset 0px -0.05em #78d64b;
     transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
     font-size:43px;
     color:#78d64b;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .hover-underline-animation-green a {
     color: #78d64b!important;
}
/*purple*/
 .hover-underline-animation-purple h3 {
     color:#e45dbf!important;
     box-shadow: inset 0 -0.0em #e45dbf;
     display: inline;
     transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .hover-underline-animation-purple h3 {
     box-shadow: inset 0px -0.05em #e45dbf;
     transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
     font-size:43px;
     color:#e45dbf;
}
 .blackcontainer:hover .hover-underline-animation-purple a {
     color: #e45dbf!important;
}
```

What is the best way to get the desired effect in the in Avada Page Builder?

Thank you

I have tried custom CSS code for the hover animations as shown above.

I tried setting the background colour on a higher parent div and then animating the padding bottom on that BUT this seemed to push up from the bottom of the div